# How to detect and capture the changed(updated) price from within <span>price</span>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, dom-events, web-frontend

I am trying to get the code below to capture the `<span></span>` content. The JQuery code seen below within a function in a custom JS file deployed on the product details page doesn't get the control as the product price changes when a variant of the configurable product is selected from the drop-down. Could you please point out what is not right in here?

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'domReady!'
], function($) {
    var docloch=document.location.href,new_title="";

    // Commented out as the Tab is not opening by default.
    // $("#tab-label-product.info.description").click();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#pmm_shipping").html('<br><div style="margin:-40px 0 15px">'+get_pmm_shipping_text()+'</div>');
    }, 750); // end of setTimeout

    // make the word CLOSEOUT red on product pages
    if ($("h1").text().indexOf("CLOSEOUT!")>-1 || $("h1").text().indexOf("OPEN BOX!")>-1){
        var newT= $("h1").html();
        newT = newT.replace("CLOSEOUT!",'<span style="color:#FF0000">CLOSEOUT!</span>');
        newT = newT.replace("OPEN BOX!",'<span style="color:#FF0000">OPEN BOX!</span>');
        $("h1").html(newT);
    }

    // THIS IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO CAPTURE THE CHANGED SPAN CONTENT
    $(".price-box").on("change", ".normal-price .price-wrapper span.price", function() {
      alert('Price Changed');
      console.log('New Price Captured ');
      // Get the value of the span element
      var price = $(".price-box .normal-price .price-wrapper span.price").html();**

      // Clean and Convert the value to cents
      var priceCents = parseInt(parseFloat(price.replace(/[^\d.]/g,'')) * 100);

      // If value is different from existing Klarna product placement value, update it.
      // and then call Klarna with refresh-event to refresh the placement.
      var oldPurchaseAmt = $(".product-add-form klarna-placement").attr("data-purchase-amount");
      if (priceCents !== oldPurchaseAmt) {
        $(".product-add-form klarna-placement").attr("data-purchase-amount", priceCents);

        // Trigger event to refresh
        window.KlarnaOnsiteService = window.KlarnaOnsiteService || [];
        window.KlarnaOnsiteService.push({ eventName: 'refresh-placements' });
      }
    });
}); // end of $ function
```

[image]

Comment: You would need to set up a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on the <span> element

Comment: I will write an answer to illustrate my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect changes in the DOM you need a MutationObserver. This is an expensive operation, and usually indicates code could be refactored, but it will suit your purposes as you've worded the question.

I've reduced your problem to the bare essentials. We have a `<span>` that contains a price, and we create a MutationObserver that watches for changes, massages the data (removes the "$" character and doubles the value, but this is just to illustrate that you can massage data). The modified value is then written to a second `<span>`.

I'm using native javascript to query the DOM, but you can use JQuery.

```js
const targetNode = document.querySelector('#watchme');
const answerNode = document.querySelector('#answer');

// change price periodically
const changePrice = () => {
    const newPrice = Math.floor( Math.random() * 16384 ) / 100;
    targetNode.innerText = '$' + newPrice;
};
window.setInterval(changePrice, 2048);

// set up Mutation Observer
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {      
        const priceAsString = mutation.target.innerText;
        const doublePrice = Number( priceAsString.replace(/^\$/g,'') ) * 2;
        answerNode.innerText = doublePrice;
    });
});

observer.observe(targetNode, { childList: true });
```

```html
<p>Original Price is: <span id="watchme"></span></p>
<p>Double Price is: <span id="answer"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts as this really is an expensive operation. Should this have been mutation.targetNode.innerText; instead of mutation.target.innerText;?

Comment: I see that because of this calle `observer.observe(targetNode, { childList: true });`  this line `mutation.target.innerText;` doesn't need change I though it would. thanks for this.

Comment: I have a question. Can I use class name instead of the ID for the span element in your code?

Comment: Yes, definitely. You can use `.price-box .normal-price` or any other [JQuery-style CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select your DOM node

Comment: Hi, I hope you are doing great. I remember your help always. I am still a beginner at JavaScript despite being in the IT for 2 years. There is a task involving only JS code, that I'm trying to first complete on the staging server. It is a part of an order management system. I would kindly request you to invest a few minutes of your valuable time in just pointing out the cause of the issue so that I will proceed from there. The issue seems to  be difficult to put in words. If you are comfortable, I share the access credentials so that you can have a look and guide me Please share your skype.

Comment: I hope you're keeping well. I've a request for you. Could you please have a look at this post to see if you can suggest some solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71910147/close-previously-opened-accordion-with-pure-javascript?noredirect=1#comment127070019_71910147

Answer (score 2):

Try text instead of html

```
var price = $(".price-box .normal-price .price-wrapper span.price").text();
```