# Close previously opened accordion with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

In a Shopify product page that has three accordions, I'm trying to add some JavaScript code to ensure only the first accordion is open by default on page load and all previously opened ones are closed.

With the following, I could only get the first accordion to appear open when the page loads. I need to add ability to close all previously open accordions when another one is clicked on. Could you please help with that? I'm looking only for a pure JS solution. The page I need to do this on is [here](https://q9rknfarvsnmqr3v-458195004.shopifypreview.com)

```
 window.onload = function() {
  var accItem = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion__item');
  // Keep the first accordion open by default.
  for (i = 0; i < accItem.length; i++) {
    console.log("Within first for loop");
    accItem[i].addEventListener('click', toggleItem, false);
  }
  function toggleItem() {
    var itemClass = this.parentNode.className;
    for (i = 0; i < accItem.length; i++) {
      console.log("Within second for loop");
      accItem[i].className = 'accordion__item close';
    }
    if (itemClass == 'accordion__item close') {
        this.parentNode.className = 'accordion__item open';
    }
  }    
 };
```

The HTML extract from the page linked above is:

```
<div class="col-12 accordion product__accordion margin__bottom--reduced">
    <input type="radio" id="a66f79b6-abe9-4e4e-9e91-0994a9c01b1b--close" name="a66f79b6-abe9-4e4e-9e91-0994a9c01b1b">
    <label class="accordion__item">
        <input type="radio" name="a66f79b6-abe9-4e4e-9e91-0994a9c01b1b">
        <span class="accordion__item--title">Description<label class="collapse" for="a66f79b6-abe9-4e4e-9e91-0994a9c01b1b--close"></label></span>
        <div class="accordion__item--content inherit ">
                        <div><p>Send them a standout gift that’s environmentally friendly and multi-functional. We’ve paired our classic cedar wood journal with a black precision-point pen to add even more beauty to the written word. A sleek, double-insulated travel tumbler helps bring their favorite beverage along for the ride—and keeps it hot or cold—from coffee to wine. Choose this gift to celebrate a colleague, relative, or friend while also supporting reforestation efforts and eco-friendly production.<br></p>
<p>Each gift is packaged in our recyclable Packed with Purpose box and includes:<br></p>
<style type="text/css"><!--
td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
--></style>
<ul>
<li>Handcrafted classic wood journal, USA-Made (6" x 9")</li>
<li>Quick-drying, smudge-resistant fine point pen in black</li>
<li>Insulated stainless steel black beverage tumbler with removable drinking lid, 10 oz.<br>
</li>
<li>An artful booklet that showcases the stories of our Impact Partners and the meaningful impact our gifts create</li>
</ul>
<p></p></div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-12 accordion product__accordion margin__bottom--reduced">
    <input type="radio" id="cfa26ceb-62c7-4683-996a-6a3f79898c4d--close" name="cfa26ceb-62c7-4683-996a-6a3f79898c4d">
    <label class="accordion__item">
        <input type="radio" name="cfa26ceb-62c7-4683-996a-6a3f79898c4d">
        <span class="accordion__item--title">Impact<label class="collapse" for="cfa26ceb-62c7-4683-996a-6a3f79898c4d--close"></label></span>
        <div class="accordion__item--content inherit ">
<div><p></p>
<style type="text/css"><!--
td {border: 1px solid #ccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
--></style>
<p><strong><a href="https://packedwithpurpose.gifts/our-impact/purposeful-purveyors/woodchuck-usa/" target="_blank"><span data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:513,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;12&quot;:0}" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;WOODCHUCK USA&quot;}">WOODCHUCK US</span>A</a></strong>&nbsp;-&nbsp;Creates eco-friendly wood products and plants one tree for every purchase made to help reforest the world; made in the USA</p>
<p><strong><a href="https://packedwithpurpose.gifts/our-impact/purposeful-purveyors/uchida/" data-mce-href="https://packedwithpurpose.gifts/our-impact/purposeful-purveyors/uchida/">Marvy Uchida</a>&nbsp;</strong>- Inspires art and creativity for all through their high-quality arts, crafts, and office products for more than 40 years</p>
<p><span data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Reduces waste and energy consumption across the entire supply chain, and packages with 100% recycled cardboard. &quot;}" data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:13185,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;10&quot;:2,&quot;11&quot;:4,&quot;12&quot;:0,&quot;15&quot;:&quot;Calibri&quot;,&quot;16&quot;:8}"><a href="https://packedwithpurpose.gifts/our-impact/purposeful-purveyors/ecovessel/"><strong>Ecovessel</strong></a>&nbsp;- Creates premium reusable drinkware to reduce the world's dependence on single-use plastics; 1% for the Planet member, woman-founded </span></p></div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-12 accordion product__accordion ">
    <input type="radio" id="04f337be-f8e2-41b0-9f06-740077e6b722--close" name="04f337be-f8e2-41b0-9f06-740077e6b722">
    <label class="accordion__item">
        <input type="radio" name="04f337be-f8e2-41b0-9f06-740077e6b722">
        <span class="accordion__item--title">Additional Info<label class="collapse" for="04f337be-f8e2-41b0-9f06-740077e6b722--close"></label></span>
        <div class="accordion__item--content inherit ">
                <p>Given the highly seasonal nature of gifting and the unique supply chain challenges presented by COVID-19, Packed with Purpose requests flexibility on the flavors, scents, and specific products featured in each gift. Our team thoroughly vets all products to guarantee any substitutions are of equal quality and impact and encompass the high standards we require of all our purveyors.</p>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the accordion ?

Comment: It is on every product page in the link shared in the post.

Comment: The information that is essential for the question should not be behind a link.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this. The helper functions act directly on the DOM elements, rather than simulating a click.

```js
//  an array of elements
const allAccordionElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".accordion__item"));

const run_code = () => {

  //  some helper functions
  const showTab = (el) => {
    el.style.display = "flex";
  };
  const hideTab = (el) => {
    el.style.display = "none";
  };

  if (allAccordionElements.length > 0) {
    
    // open the first one
    showTab(allAccordionElements[0]);
    
    //  hide all others
    allAccordionElements.slice(1).forEach(thisTab => {
      hideTab(thisTab);
    });  
  
  }
  
};

document.getElementById('run').addEventListener('click',run_code);
```

```css
.accordion__item {
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border: 2px dotted green;
  background-color: silver;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">

  <div class="accordion__item">
    item one
  </div>
  <div class="accordion__item">
    item two
  </div>
  <div class="accordion__item">
    item three
  </div>

</div>

<button id="run">run code</button>
```

Comment: Hiding the according elements and closing them are two different actions. With your code the other accordion elements disappear and are not available to be clicked on again.

Comment: in fact OP's code uses `display: none` to hide the `.accordion__item` element, whereas a <radio /> element next to it in the DOM tree remains visible. I didn't include all that markup because it's not salient to the question

Comment: @code_monk could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active element? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked

Answer (score 0):

The accordion controls set the `max-height` CSS property to either `0` or `420`. It is as simple as setting each accordion accordingly (hehe).

To OPEN:

```
.accordion__item .accordion__item--content { max-height: 420; }
```

To CLOSE:

```
.accordion__item .accordion__item--content { max-height: 0; }
```

Solution is to replace the click event with this:

EDIT: I made a typo in the first post. Remove `[0]` and replace with the `forEach` loop as shown below.

```
window.onload = function() {
  let allAccordionElements = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion__item .accordion__item--content");
  if (allAccordionElements.length > 0) {
    // Close all to start
    allAccordionElements.forEach(a=>a.style.maxHeight = "0"); 
    // Open the first
    allAccordionElements[0].style.maxHeight = "420"; 
  } 
};
```

Comment: This isn't working, you can visit the page by clicking the link in my post. Please check it.

Comment: right - I edited the post with new code. I made a mistake in the original post.

Comment: should it not be `420px`?

Comment: I tried the edited version. The result is all accordions are overlapping one another in the collapsed fashion

Comment: I used the wrong selector - Look at the selector in the answer - I've now changed to solution code to use the correct selector.